# iOS: How to have a small view visible in many views without initializing it in every view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uiview

Just as the title states, I am looking to have a small notification view that will be present in all views of the application. Is there a way to do this without initializing it in every single view?

Comment: Not unless you want to pass the view between controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Attach it to the `UIWindow` object. This way it will be available on every view.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface SharedViewManager {
}

+ (UIView*) getSharedView;
@end



@implementation SharedViewManager 

static UIView* sharedView = nil;

+ (UIView*) getSharedView {
    if (sharedView == nil) {
        //initialize the view
    }
    return sharedView;
}

@end
```